# Concatenate two data frames with the same name from different directories via Python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have two folders in different directories that contain excel files with the same name.
I need to concatenate the excel files, not sheets, because each file has one sheet, that have the same name.
for example:

**d1 contains A, B, C files**

**d2 contains A, B, E, F file**

**The output should contain two files**, the result from concatenating **A from d1 and A from d2**, and the result from concatenating **B from d1 and B from d2**.

If d1 and d2 have no files with the same name, there will be no output.

the first data frame has multiple rows but the second data frame has one row. When I run this code, it considers the second data frame as a header, and when I set the header as false it no longer takes it under consideration.

```
import glob
import numpy as np

file_d1 = glob.glob(d1 + "/*.xlsx")
file_d2 = glob.glob(d2 + "/*.xlsx")
i=0
for file_d1 in glob.glob(d1 + "/*.xlsx"):
    fileName_d1 = os.path.splitext(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_d1))[0])[0]
    for file_d2 in glob.glob(d2 + "/*.xlsx"):
        fileName_d2 = os.path.splitext(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_d2))[0])[0]
        if fileName_d1 == fileName_d2:
            i+=1
            fileName_1=d1+'/'+fileName_d1+'.xlsx'
        df1 = pd.read_excel(fileName_1, header=0, index= False)
        fileName_2=d2+'/'+fileName_d2+'.xlsx'
        df2 = pd.read_excel(fileName_2, header=0, index= False)
        print(fileName_1)
        print(fileName_2)
        df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([df1.values, df2.values], axis=0), columns=df2.columns)
df.to_excel('C:/Users/khouloud.ayari/Desktop/FinalResult/output'+str(i)+'.xlsx', index = True, header=False)
```

What should I do to get the correct output, which is (1st data frame + 2nd data frame) not the other way around?

when I concatenated the two files, the "nbr de Reboot" was gone and the "nbr de km parcourus" was considered as a header `df.to_excel('C:/Users/khouloud.ayari/Desktop/FinalResult/output'+str(i)+'.xlsx', index = False, header=True)`

**output via console**

```
1   nbr de Kilomètres parcourus  1
0       Passage en mode privé  1
1      Passage en mode public  2
```

**output .xlsx**

[image]

**expected output:**
[image]
A and B are three different files

PS: I'm using Python 3.7(Spyder)

Comment: How does that directory structure look for both of those - and their sheet structure?

Comment: the directory only contains excel files( is this what you mean by directory structure?)

Comment: Is it the file name you're wanting to use to align things, or is it the sheet names within them?

Comment: So say there's N many files in d1, (called whatever) some have sheets, A, B, C and there's M many files in d2 some have sheets called (A, D, E) etc... what's the combined output?

Comment: the file name.
I need to concatenate files(from different directories) with the same name

Comment: @JonClements I'm working with files, not sheets, I guess my code is wrong, and the output should concatenate M1 file in d1 and M1 file in d2 because each file has one-sheet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200335/discussion-between-jon-clements-and-a-khou).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My goal was to concatenate two excel files with the same name located in different directories but I failed to do so because some data was lost in the process, so I added headers to my excel files and I run the code below:

```
import os 
import pandas as pd

d2 = "C:/Users/khouloud/Desktop/d2"
d1 = "C:/Users/khouloud/Desktop/d1"

import glob
import numpy as np
file_d1 = glob.glob(d1 + "/*.xlsx")
file_d2 = glob.glob(d2 + "/*.xlsx")
i=0
for file_d1 in glob.glob(d1 + "/*.xlsx"):
    fileName_d1 = os.path.splitext(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_d1))[0])[0]
    for file_d2 in glob.glob(d2 + "/*.xlsx"):
        fileName_d2 = os.path.splitext(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_d2))[0])[0]
        if fileName_d1 == fileName_d2:
            i+=1
            fileName_1=d1+'/'+fileName_d1+'.xlsx'
            df1 = pd.read_excel(fileName_1, header=0, index= False)
            fileName_2=d2+'/'+fileName_d2+'.xlsx'
            df2 = pd.read_excel(fileName_2, header=0, index= False)
            df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([df1.values, df2.values]), columns=df2.columns)
            print('**********************************************')
            print('1',df)
            print('**********************************************')
            df.to_excel('C:/Users/khouloud/Desktop/FinalResult/output'+str(i)+'.xlsx', index = False, header=False)
```